# Qt cpp code..how object.function1.function2 works

Tags: c++, qt

I am unable to get how this will work...
how object.function1.function2 works
following is the code
l_floatValue = l_objMeter.getWATTHrs().getChannelA();

Comment: The same way it would work without Qt in the picture.  The first function returns an object or reference that has a function itself.  If you have a specific example that isn't clear you should edit the question to include that, otherwise this is a very simple C++ question.

Comment: means getWATTHrs() will return me an object..and getchannelA will be function for that object..

Comment: what this type of syntax is called?? so that i can study it over internet.. will be helpful if you post some link..thnks in advnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

function 1 retrun you object and you call method of it

Comment: what this type of syntax is called?? so that i can study it over internet.. will be helpful if you post some link..thnks in advnce

Answer (score 0):

Please consider following example

```
  int len = QString(" TEST ").simplified().length();
```

Suppose

```
  QString test = QString(" TEST ");  // will create string object of lengh 6
  QString simTest = test.simplified(); // Will create string of len 4 remove white spaces
  int len = simTest.length(); // len 4
```

This is how program will work